# maven problems, "mvn package" not run

Tags: maven

```
The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (E:\TAMK\Software Architectures\new-awesome-prj\my-app). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

i build my prj with the code with double quotes due to the fact that it won't work without it

```
mvn archetype:generate "-DgroupId=com.mycompany" "-DartifactId=quartz-poc" "-DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart" "-DarchetypeVersion=1.4" "-DinteractiveMode=false"
```

but when i try to `mvn package` for its already build "hello world" it happens to appear like this again, same with when i build prj with the normal without quote line `mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.4 -DinteractiveMode=false`

Comment: Have you read the message "there is no POM in this directory (E:\TAMK\Software Architectures\new-awesome-prj\my-app)"?